# How can I save multiple string values from settings.LANGUAGES to a model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have Account model in Django.

```
class Account(models.Model):
name =   CharField(max_length=255)
description =  CharField(max_length=500)
image_path =  CharField(max_length=255)
languages = models.ListField()
```

Since Django doesn't have ListField, it gives an error. So how can I store multiple string values (choices will be from settings.LANGUAGES)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is create a model for `Language` choices and make a many to many relation with `Account`

```
class LanguageChoices(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Account(models.Model):
   name =   CharField(max_length=255)
   description =  CharField(max_length=500)
   image_path =  CharField(max_length=255)
   languages = models.ManyToManyField(LanguageChoices)
```

but that has the disadvantage that the choices have to be put in a database. If you want to use hard coded choices, this is probably not what you want.

There is a django snippet at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/ that does seem to solve your problem, by implementing a ModelField MultipleChoiceField

Comment: Actually I don't want to save it into database.

Comment: Even if you have `ListField` you should have to save these in db, above django snippet helps you, or change it according to your needs.